# WooCommerce - How to Call an Xero Action

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, xero-api

I have some code that generates a WooCommerce order in the backend using wc_create_order(). My issue is that none of the order actions get called like they would if you had made an order through the front end. For example I have the Xero plugin integrated with WooCommerce but if I create the order using wc_create_order() the invoice never gets sent to my Xero account.

What I want to know is how could I trigger the following xero invoice order action (shown in image on woocommerce order) without having to go to the order page and manually send them.

[image]

I have possibly found the action I want to call manually it can be found in the setup_hooks() function on this page [git hub link.](https://github.com/danicampora/woocommerce-xero/blob/master/classes/class-wc-xr-order-actions.php) Is it possible for me to call the woocommerce_order_action_xero_manual_invoice action manually if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to call `do_action('woocommerce_order_action_xero_manual_invoice', $order)`.

`$order` must be an object of class `WC_Order`.